# Cactus brown root

Tags: cactus

I have this 3 year old cactus and recently discovered that his bottom is brown. The thing is, the brown part is very hard and I heard that in order to be rotten it should be soft? I have no idea what to do, do you think it will survive like this or do I have to cut the brown part and replant the rest?

Comment: Water less. One thing we know is that cactus does object to underwatering.

Comment: Hi there, can you add a picture?